# Swift: For-in loop requires '[DeepSpeechTokenMetadata]' to conform to 'Sequence'

Tags: swift, for-in-loop

I'm running into a weird error with a for in loop and an array. it says

```
For-in loop requires '[DeepSpeechTokenMetadata]' to conform to 'Sequence'
```

Which doesn't make any sense... it knows it's an Array...

The for loop in question:

```
      var transcriptCandidate = decoded.transcripts[0].tokens
      var words = [String]()
      var timestamps = [Int]()

      var workingString = ""
      var lastTimestamp = -1
      for (x, token) in transcriptCandidate {
        let text = token.text
        let timestamp = token.startTime
        if(lastTimestamp == -1){
          lastTimestamp = timestamp.toInt()
        }
```

Here's the definition of the class that contains the array I'm trying to iterate through:

```
public struct DeepSpeechCandidateTranscript {
    /// Array of DeepSpeechTokenMetadata objects
    public private(set) var tokens: [DeepSpeechTokenMetadata] = []

    /** Approximated confidence value for this transcript. This corresponds to
        both acoustic model and language model scores that contributed to the
        creation of this transcript.
    */
    let confidence: Double

    internal init(fromInternal: CandidateTranscript) {
        let tokensBuffer = UnsafeBufferPointer<TokenMetadata>(start: fromInternal.tokens, count: Int(fromInternal.num_tokens))
        for tok in tokensBuffer {
            tokens.append(DeepSpeechTokenMetadata(fromInternal: tok))
        }
        confidence = fromInternal.confidence
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: decoded.transcripts[0].tokens - what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either do this, where `x` is the index and `token` is the element:

```
for (x, token) in transcriptCandidate.enumerated() {
}
```

Or this if you don't need the index:

```
for token in transcriptCandidate {
}
```