# iOS Swift iterate over an Array of Dictionary Items from Firestore

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to iterate over the following dictionary:

[Dictionary in Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgNwB.png)

This is my code:

```
Global.sharedInstance.db.collection("usuarios").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("error de lectura usuarios...")
    } else {
        if let snapshot = snapshot {
            for document in snapshot.documents {
                let data = document.data()
                let txtIdentificador = data["identificador"] as? String ?? ""
                let txtBio = data["bio"] as? String ?? ""
                let txtNombre = data["nombre_usuario"] as? String ?? ""
                let txtFotoPerfil = data["foto_perfil"] as? String ?? ""
                
                var arrFotos = data["fotos"] as? [String: [String:String]]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to retrieve the first few lines, like the id, the biography, name, etc.
But when I try to access the array of dictionary I have no idea.

**This is the main idea:**
I have a set of users, which I iterate over with the first loop 'for document in documents...", then each user has a set of photos. I want to iterate over the 3 photos, and in each iteration I want to retrieve the fields, so I can create a object called Image and associate the user with the 'hasUpload(Image)'.

I would like to know how to iterate over X photos an in each iteration retrieve the fields.

Something like this:

```
var arrFotos = data["fotos"] as? [String: [String:String]]
for foto in arrFotos {
    for (key,value) in foto {
        
    }
}
```

I get the error: For-in loop requires '[String : [String : String]]?' to conform to 'Sequence'; did you mean to unwrap optional?

Comment: Have you seen this similar case on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63609283/swift-for-in-loop-requires-deepspeechtokenmetadata-to-conform-to-sequence) ?

Answer (score 0):

A similar StackOverflow case can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63609283/swift-for-in-loop-requires-deepspeechtokenmetadata-to-conform-to-sequence) and this is how they resolved it:

You can either do this, where x is the index and token is the element:

```
for (x, token) in transcriptCandidate.enumerated() {
}
```

Or this if you don't need the index:

```
for token in transcriptCandidate {
}
```